# It is possible to use relative path in discord api in python?

Tags: python, discord.py

Good Morning, 
I develop a discord bot in python thanks to Discord API. So I want to upload an image with this bot and in the code I want to use a relative path, for simplification when it will be upload on a server. But it didn't work. I am obliged to use the absolute path which is not very usefull. Do you have any solution please.
Thank you.

```py
@bot.command()
async def command(ctx):
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File('photos/picture.jpg'))
```

Here the terminal :

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/photos/picture.jpg'
```

Comment: Relative path should work fine. Please update your question to include your code. In particular, a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: How are you running the bot? Straight from an IDE, from command line/terminal, or something else?

Comment: have you tried `./photos/picture.jpg`?

Comment: @Benjin I run it from Visual Studio Code. But I just tried with the python IDLE and it works.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/lates)

```
file = discord.File("path/to/my/image.png", filename="image.png")
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
await channel.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```